# Getting InRequestScope object in MVC Filters

Tags: asp.net, filter, ninject, scopes

As far as i know ASP MVC caches filters -> so they are not bound in request scope thus if i will ask ninject inside it for an instance of object i will get it in completly new scope.

In Web-Api I can use actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope() where actionContext :: HttpActionContext to retrieve objects instances from request scope. I have been googling for some time and I cannot find anything similar in MVC. So the main qustion is :: Is there any way to retrieve object instances bound in request scope inside MVC filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look at the implementation of Ninject.web.mvcX `InRequestScope()`.
It uses `HttpContext.Current` as scope object.

That means, if you've got

```
Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().InRequestScope();
```

you can inject use

`IResolutionRoot.Get<IFoo>()`

basically anywhere/anytime at which `HttpContext.Current` is "valid".

To bind the filter, you can use the ninject.web.mvcX nuget package and do:

```
BindFilter<FooFilter>(FilterScope.Controller, 0)
```

This allows you to use ctor-injection with the filter. Also see [Ninject Wiki: Dependency Injection for Filters](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Dependency-injection-for-filters)

I'm not quite sure whether this changes when / how often filters are instanciated, but i don't think so. So in order to access an `InRequestScope()` object in your filter, you'll have to inject an `IResolutionRoot` or - even better - a factory (see [ninject.extensions.factory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.factory)) into your filter to create the object / object graph.

Comment: What do u mean by IResolutionRoot?

Comment: the `NinjectKernel` or `StandardKernel` implements two interfaces: `IResolutionRoot` (used for instanciating objects/object graphs, p.Ex. `Get<IFoo>()`) and `IBindingRoot` (used for creating bindings, p.Ex `Bind<IFoo>()`). In your web-app the `DependencyResolver` is doing `IResolutionRoot.Get<T>()` everytime something is instantiated. You can also have `IResolutionRoot` injected somewhere and use it to instantiate stuff. This is called `ServiceLocator` and is mostly an anti-pattern, that means, use it only if there's no better solution.